# deactivate sound in as3 when the game terminates or loses focus

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am trying to deactivate the sound of my application when the user terminates or close the application, for which I have used an event listener:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, onDeactivate);//error

private function onDeactivate(e:Event)
{
            _channel.stop();
}
```

But it is not working:

> error:Access of undefined property DEACTIVATE
>   -1119: Access of possibly undefined property DEACTIVATE through a reference with static type Class.

Sugessions please.

Comment: Did you import `flash.events.Event`?

Comment: yes i did.. but still its not working

Comment: Does the class you are using extend `DisplayObject`? If not, you won't have access to `stage`. (If that were the case, the error would happen due to stage being undefined, not DEACTIVATE. But I figure it is worth a shot)

Comment: Are you targeting Flash Player 9+? The docs say that's when DEACTIVATE was added. I'd guess you are, but thought it was worth asking.  Also, you don't happen to have any other classes named Event imported do you?